# Neo4j service stops

Tags: neo4j

all. I'm running neo4j on Ubuntu on Digital Ocean. The Neo4j service repeatedly quits with nothing of interest in the log files and no discernible pattern. I'm new to neo4j and not sure where to start exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm - how is the service launched (via service / systemctl script) or bin/neo4j start

Comment: bin/neo4j start, @ChrisWhite. Thanks!